# Android telephony dtmf

Tags: android, telephony, dtmf

I have researched extensively and am pretty sure this is not possible. I want to make a call and then inject DTMF when the far end answers. So 2 questions

1. Is it possible ?
2. If not, how do I work to get it on the list of upcoming features to be provided on Android

I can say that this is possible on BlackBerry and Symbian, so Android is falling behind in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is at the time you dial, you can add DTMF at the end of the phone number. For example, you call this number 6215551234 just add ,1234 at the end:

```
tel:6215551234,1234
```

The comma is a 2 second pause. The 1234 is the DTMF you will send. Now it's just a matter of using the right number of commas. (It is also impossible to be notified when the other end of the call is answering.)

If you want to send the DTMF in the middle of a call, can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Emmanuel, just as I suspected. Mind you, I am getting more like 4s delay with the comma, which makes lack of this feature even more frustrating.

I also since found it on the feature wish list [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1428) so have a look and vote for it if you think it is important.